# Self require is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have created a file constant.js

```
var  self = require("./constant");
module.exports = {
   FirstName : "sourabh",
   LastName : "gupta",
   Name: self.FirstName + " " + self.LastName
}
```

here, in **constant.js**

I defined two properties in object FirstName, LastName and third property Name is based on the above two property which i define by requiring the same file.

I am expecting that when another file require the constant.js. let **main.js**

```
var constant = require('./constant.js');
console.log("constants>>>>>"+JSON.strinigfy(constant));   //will print {FirstName : "sourabh",LastName : "gupta",Name: "sourabh gupta"}

 //but its prints - {FirstName : "sourabh",LastName : "gupta"}  -- Name is undefined
```

As much i know this is happening due to require cache which return the constant mudule value as blank json {}.

so, i want to know that is it possible any how to get the json - {FirstName : "sourabh",LastName : "gupta",Name: "sourabh gupta"}

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `constant.js`?

Comment: Are you returning out of constant.js? Can you show constant.js?

Comment: i have given the code of constant.js. it call itself

Comment: How is that supposed to work exactly?! It's a recursive declaration with at best no clearly defined expected result.

Comment: I have update the query please check

Comment: This *cannot* work. If `require` would actually try to include the module when called, you'd have an endless recursive `require` chain which never resolves. Since it *does* resolve, it cannot possibly hold a value which is yet undefined.